# Extract numpy arrays from pandas dataframe as matrix

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I ended up with the following data structure:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,3]})
my_df['col_1'] = my_df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: np.array([1,2,3]))
my_df.as_matrix()
```

it looks like this:

```
array([[array([1, 2, 3])],
       [array([1, 2, 3])],
       [array([1, 2, 3])]], dtype=object)
```

Whily I would like it to look like simply numpy matrix. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want an array, you can

```
np.array(my_df.col_1.tolist())

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply it to multiple columns at once?